# How to sort an array of structures according to the value of an included pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers, structure

my aim is to sort an array of structures. The structure contains the index of a customer {1,..., number} and a pointer to a value of an other sturcture,

e.g,

```
for (int i = 1; i < no_orders+1; i++){
     sorting_array[i].index_order = i;
     sorting_array[i].some_vaule = &order_data[i].some_value;
                }
```

Here, `order_data` is an array of structures contains all customer data which allows for directly accessing variable data a customer the index. The array `sorting_array` is the one to sort according to a value in order_data; therefore the pointer in DATA_TO_SORT in order to avoid copying effort since this function is called millions of times (same indices, changed values).

The actual problem appears with the sorting function. If I do not use the pointer but the real value (int some_value, including copying effort however), sorting works as it should.

Defining some_value as pointer, `std::sort` terminates after some seconds without any feedback the whole program. The actual question is why and what may I change.

```
struct DATA_TO_SORT {

        int index_order;
        int *some_value;
    };

    bool compare_by_val( DATA_TO_SORT &a,  DATA_TO_SORT &b) {

        return *a.some_value > *b.some_value;
    }

    void sort_acc_release() {
        std::sort(sorting_array.begin() + 1, sorting_array.end(), compare_by_val);
    }
```

Also tried the following from a related topic, however, the depicted error statement occurs - besides several similar error statements.

```
std::sort(sorting_array.begin() + 1, sorting_array.end(), [&](size_t a, size_t b) {return *sorting_array[a].some_value > *sorting_array[b].some_value; });
```

> <lambda_0a6c4bdbc69eba5706031ee8a4b875c6>::operator ()(::size_t,::size_t) const" : Konvertierung von Argument 1 von "DATA_TO_SORT" in "::size_t" nicht möglich Algorithm   ...\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility   1017

Minimum Example which WORKS.

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <cstdlib>  //rand
#include <algorithm>  //swap etc
#include <array>    //array


struct OTHER_DATA {

    int other_data;
};

struct DATA_TO_SORT {

    int index_order;
    int *some_value;
};

bool compare_by_val(DATA_TO_SORT &a, DATA_TO_SORT &b) {

    return *a.some_value > *b.some_value;
}


int main() {

    const int max_no = 10;

    std::array<OTHER_DATA, max_no> some_other_values;
    std::array<DATA_TO_SORT, 10> sorting_array;

    for (int i = 0; i < some_other_values.size(); i++)
    {
        some_other_values[i].other_data = i * 5;
        sorting_array[i].index_order = i;
        sorting_array[i].some_value = &some_other_values[i].other_data;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < sorting_array.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n" <<  sorting_array[i].index_order << "\t" << *sorting_array[i].some_value;
    }
    std::sort(sorting_array.begin(), sorting_array.end(), compare_by_val);


    for (int i = 0; i < sorting_array.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << sorting_array[i].index_order << "\t" << *sorting_array[i].some_value;
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your problem-related and well-intentioned answers!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Do the pointers actually point somewhere? If not that would explain sudden crashes

Comment: The arguments of your comparator are expected to be elements of the container. It doesn't look like `sorting_array` contains `size_t`s.

Comment: is it possible that you edited your code and introduced more errors than there actually are in your real code? eg `a.release_data`, your `DATA_TO_SORT` has no `release_data`, did you mean `some_value` ?

Comment: yes, edited it and providing an complete minimal example, sry.

Comment: include algorithm, declare sorting_array, why skip first entry when sorting? It compiles if I fill in stuff with my best guess as to what you meant. You probably should take const reference in the comparator.

Comment: Arrays start at 1? Are you certain your pointers are not pointing into garbage memory at the time of sort?

Comment: no problem [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qnlHNsVzkIwulOuY). This is the code that terminates after few seconds?

Comment: @all Thank you for your time, the minimum example suggested in the first comment is included and WORKS - so there may be other issues I have to find. 

KennyOstrom Thank you, I'll try.

NeilGatenby Thank you, excluding the first is on purpose and the array defined by n+1.

Comment: sorry, but if the mcve does not reproduce the error you have, then it is not a mcve ;). Please next time try to prepare one before writing the question. Often it makes you find the problem yourself and if not it helps us to help you

Comment: The error was caused by a wrong  last iterator definition in sort(first, last, comp). Array was defined by const int max_n and only the first n elements are used.